# I need help to write this equation

Tags: equations

I wrote the equation like this... But it's showing error. It will be really helpful if someone could help me out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}

\wedge F = 
\frac 
   {\sum{n=1}^{N}\bigl(\wedge x_k + 1 - \wedge F \wedge x _k \bigr)}
   {\sum{n=1}^{N} \wedge x ^{2}_k}

\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You probably mean `\hat` (an accent) instead of `\wedge` (a symbol). Lower limit on sum is marked using a `_`. Also please cite the error you get. Rembrandt that blank lines in the code are not allowed inside math constructions.

Comment: Is the code as displayed now, after my edit, the way you have it in your editor? In that case the only thing causing an error is that you have blank lines inside the `displaymath` environment. As @daleif says, that is not allowed. (Edit: there are other problems as well though, as daleif mentioned.)

Comment: Thanks for help, \wedge was giving me error... I don't  know why my course book ask to include that... Thank you so much

Comment: Good idea to also include the amssymb package, gives you access to more symbols than the standard. Also probably a good idea to use the equation* env instead of the displaymath env (hardly anyone is using that any more). equation* is provided by amsmath (which you load) and make it easy to switch to a numbered equation (just remove the *)

Answer (score 1):

So I did it like this and it worked

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\hat F = 
\frac 
   {\sum_{k=1}^{N}\bigl(\hat x_{k + 1} - \hat F \hat x _k \bigr)}
   {\sum_{k=1}^{N} \hat x ^{2}_k}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```